# A problem with analysing the 'Delta Function Normalization', of an 'Irregular Coulomb Wave Function'.

Tags: dirac-delta, quantum-mechanics

**Edit May 24th 2022**

Please note, I no longer think that

\begin{equation*}
\int _0^\infty G_L(\eta,~k^\prime r) G_L(\eta,~kr) dr = N_{L,G} \delta(k-k^\prime)
\end{equation*}

for some real number $N_{L,G}$. See also, my answer, to this question, ( dated May 10th 2021 ).

I have left this question, as it was though, apart from this edit.

**End of edit**

A one dimensional momentum eigenfunction $ e^{ikx}$, can be normalized in terms of the 'Dirac Delta Function',  we can write that, for some value of $C$

\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ik^\prime x} e^{ikx} dx = C \delta( k-k^\prime)
\end{equation*}

$C$ can be evaluated, $C=2\pi$, see Reference 1,

I think that both the  'Regular Coulomb Wave Function', $F(\eta,~\rho)$ ,  and the  'Irregular Coulomb Wave Function' $G(\eta,~\rho)$, can also be normalised in terms of the delta function, with the numbers,  $N_{L,F},~N_{L,G}$  each measuring the"ratios" of two infinities.

So, we should have, for some values of $N_{L,F}$ and $N_{L,G}$
\begin{equation*}
\int _0^\infty F_L(\eta,~k^\prime r) F_L(\eta,~kr) dr = N_{L,F} \delta(k-k^\prime)
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\int _0^\infty G_L(\eta,~k^\prime r) G_L(\eta,~kr) dr = N_{L,G} \delta(k-k^\prime)
\end{equation*}

My understanding is, that $F_L(\eta,~ \rho)$ and  $G_L(\eta,~ \rho)$, are  real valued functions, so their complex conjugate functions, are themselves.

See  'Other Information', for the definitions of $F_L(\eta, ~\rho)$ and  $G_L(\eta, ~\rho)$, the defining equations are quoted from Abramowitz and Stegun$^2$.

It can be argued, see 'Other Information', that for our purposes, the $F_L$ integral, behaves essentially the same as one, with $F_L$  replaced by it's asymptotic form $F_{L,a}$, see at the beginning of 'Other Information'.

So we have
\begin{equation*}
\int _0^\infty F_{L,a}(\eta,~k^\prime r) F_{L,a}(\eta,~kr) dr = N_{L,F} \delta(k-k^\prime)
\end{equation*}

I would like to do the same "trick" with the $G_L$ integral but it seems problematical. I think that there are maybe two infinities associated with the $G_L$ integral. One associated with the form of $G_L$, oscillating out to infinity, and possibly one to do with $G_L$, going to infinity at $r=0, ( or \rho = kr=0 )$

Could anyone help me with this difficulty? Perhaps you can tell me how to justify the following?

\begin{equation*}
\int _0^\infty G_{L,a}(\eta,~k^\prime r) G_{L,a}(\eta,~kr) dr = N_{L,G} \delta(k-k^\prime)
\end{equation*}

$G_{L,a}$ being the asymptotic form of $G_L$.

References

1. See the materials at

https://sites.google.com/site/rwhawksworthexamples/home/math/dirac-delta-function-various-pages/delta-function-normalization/momentum-eigenfunctions

within which it is proved, that $C$ has the value $2\pi$.

2. See at

https://archive.org/details/AandS-mono600/page/n551/mode/2up

**Other Information**

**Replacing $F_L$ by it's asymptotic form $F_{L,a}$, supporting argument.**

NB Adding or subtracting a finite quantity, to or from respectively, one that is infinite, cannot really affect the infinite quantity. So the following should be OK when $k=k^\prime$.

\begin{equation*}
\int _0^\infty F_L(\eta,~k^\prime r) F_L(\eta,~kr) dr = \int _0^{r_a} F_L(\eta,~k^\prime r) F_L(\eta,~kr) dr + \int _{r_a}^\infty F_{L,a}(\eta,~k^\prime r) F_{L,a}(\eta,~kr) dr
\end{equation*}
where, $F_L$ has it's asymptotic form $F_{L,a}$, for any $r>r_a$.

What we are interested in, with evaluating $N_{L,F}$, is in finding the ratio of the infinity in '$\int _0^\infty F_L(\eta,~k^\prime r) F_L(\eta,~kr) dr$', when $k^\prime=k$, to the infinity in '$ \delta(k-k^\prime)$'.

Introducing the symbol '$\doteq$' to mean 'for our purposes may be replaced by',

we may put,

\begin{equation*}
\int _0^\infty F_L(\eta,~k^\prime r) F_L(\eta,~kr) dr \doteq \int _{r_a}^\infty F_{L,a}(\eta,~k^\prime r) F_{L,a}(\eta,~kr) dr
\end{equation*}

\begin{align*}
\int _{r_a}^\infty F_{L,a}(\eta,~k^\prime r) F_{L,a}(\eta,~kr) dr &\doteq  \int _{r_a}^\infty F_{L,a}(\eta,~k^\prime r) F_{L,a}(\eta,~kr) dr+        \int _0^{r_a} F_{L,a}(\eta,~k^\prime r) F_{L,a}(\eta,~kr) dr \\
&= \int _0^\infty F_{L,a}(\eta,~k^\prime r) F_{L,a}(\eta,~kr) dr
\end{align*}

Hence,

\begin{equation*}
\int _0^\infty F_L(\eta,~k^\prime r) F_L(\eta,~kr) dr \doteq \int _0^\infty F_{L,a}(\eta,~k^\prime r) F_{L,a}(\eta,~kr) dr
\end{equation*}

when $k=k^\prime$.

**WHEN $k\neq k^\prime$**

Ignoring the possible orthogonality of eigenfunctions here, anyone with a comment?

Thinking in terms of continuity, when $k\approx k^\prime$ the infinity in $\int _0^\infty F_L(\eta,~k^\prime r) F_L(\eta,~kr) dr $ should still be a very large number, so the above "equations" of the argument should still be OK. Hence should be usefull in considering certain limiting behaviour.

For larger and larger $\lvert k-k^\prime \lvert$ the equations are probably more and more dubious.

**Equations from Abramowitz and Stegun$^2$,  see the provided link**

$\mathbf{14.1.3}$
\begin{equation*}
F_L(\eta,~ \rho)= C_L(\eta) \rho^{L+1} e^{  -i\rho  }~M( L+1-i\eta,~2L+2,~2i\rho   )
\end{equation*}

$\mathbf{14.1.14}$
\begin{equation*}
G_L(\eta,~ \rho)=\frac{ 2\eta  }  { C_0^2(\eta)  }~F_L(\eta,~ \rho)
\left[ ~ln~2\rho+ \frac{q_L(\eta)  }{ p_L(\eta  } \right]
+\theta_L(\eta,~\rho)
\end{equation*}

To get on top of these definitions, various other results from  Abramowitz and Stegun$^2$, need to be taken into account.

Related questions, see at

[How do you work out, the 'Delta Function Normalization', of a 'Regular Coulomb Wave Function'?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4129194/how-do-you-work-out-the-delta-function-normalization-of-a-regular-coulomb-w)

[About the idea that, the "Normalization" of a "scattering wavefunction", being insensitive to the functions form near to the scattering centre.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4132968/about-the-idea-that-the-normalization-of-a-scattering-wavefunction-being-i)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4153211/is-this-the-way-to-delta-function-normalise-a-continuum-wave-function

and

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/635101/finding-two-remarks-in-diracs-the-principles-of-quantum-mechanics

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe the 'trick' applied to the $F_L$ integral can be applied to the $G_L$ integral.

Its not a problem though because you never need

\begin{equation*}
\int _0^\infty G_L(\eta,~k^\prime r) G_L(\eta,~kr)~ dr = N_{L,G} \delta(k-k^\prime)
\end{equation*}

The irregular solution $G_L$, at $r=0$, is never used as part of a continuum wave function. $G_L$ only appears in asymptotic forms of such wave functions, as $r \to \infty$.

---

**Other Information**

The asymptotic forms of $F_L$ and $G_L$ are given in Section 14.5 of Abramowitz and Stegun$^2$.

To lowest order of approximation, as $\rho\to \infty$, (14.5.1) and (14.5.2) become
\begin{align*}
F_L&=g_0\cos \theta_L+f_0\sin \theta_L \\
G_L&=f_0\cos \theta_L-g_0\sin \theta_L 
\end{align*}

giving

\begin{align*}
F_L&=\sin \theta_L \\
G_L&=\cos \theta_L
\end{align*}

See after (14.5.8) for $f_0=1$, and $g_0=0$, also see (14.5.5) for the definition of $\theta_L$.

So the  Abramowitz and Stegun$^2$  definitions of $F_L$ and $G_L$ are consistent with their asymptotic forms being sinusoids of unit amplitude.