# About the idea that, the "Normalization" of a "scattering wavefunction", being insensitive to the functions form near to the scattering centre.

Tags: dirac-delta, quantum-mechanics

I thought I saw ..., well, not a pussy cat, but a comment in Dirac$^1$, going on about the "Normalization" of a scattering wave function being insensitive to the form of such a wavefunction close to the scattering centre ( hence origin of coordinates ).

How well, can this idea be justified?

If the idea is justifiable, it could be of use in setting up an expression I would like to use, in working out the 'Delta Function Normalization' of the 'Irregular Coulomb Wave Function', see at

[A problem with analysing the 'Delta Function Normalization', of an 'Irregular Coulomb Wave Function'.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4130849/a-problem-with-analysing-the-delta-function-normalization-of-an-irregular-co)

Reference

1. P.A.M. Dirac, The Principles Of Quantum Mechanics 4th Ed., Clarendon Press, Oxford, 1958

$~~$

**Related Questions**

[Is this the way to delta-function normalise a continuum wave function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4153211/is-this-the-way-to-delta-function-normalise-a-continuum-wave-function)

[How do you work out, the 'Delta Function Normalization', of a 'Regular Coulomb Wave Function'?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4129194/how-do-you-work-out-the-delta-function-normalization-of-a-regular-coulomb-w)

[About the idea that, the "Normalization" of a "scattering wavefunction", being insensitive to the functions form near to the scattering centre.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4132968/about-the-idea-that-the-normalization-of-a-scattering-wavefunction-being-i)

and

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/635101/finding-two-remarks-in-diracs-the-principles-of-quantum-mechanics

Answer (score 1):

The idea can be justified from a mathematical point of view. This justification uses the idea that, adding or subtracting a finite quantity, to or from an infinite one, cannot really make a difference to the infinity.

Let $r_a$ be the radial coordinate beyond which a real valued continuum wave function adopts its asymptotic form, and let $\Psi_{k,L}(r)$ be the radial part of such a wave function, in some central potential, so that $\Psi_{k,L,a}(r)$, is it's asymptotic form for any $r>r_a$.

**For** $\mathbf{k=k^\prime}$ , so that the first integral below is infinite

We have

\begin{align*}
\int _0^\infty \Psi_{k,L}(r) \Psi_{{k^\prime} ,L}(r) dr &= \int _0^{r_a} \Psi_{k,L}(r) \Psi_{{k^\prime },L}(r) dr + \int _{r_a}^\infty \Psi_{k,L,a}(r) \Psi_{{k^\prime} ,L,a}(r) dr \\
&=\int _{r_a}^\infty \Psi_{k,L,a}(r) \Psi_{{k^\prime} ,L,a}(r) dr \\
&=\int ^{r_a}_0 \Psi_{k,L,a}(r) \Psi_{{k^\prime} ,L,a}(r) dr + \int _{r_a}^\infty \Psi_{k,L,a}(r) \Psi_{{k^\prime} ,L,a}(r) dr\\
&=\int _0^\infty \Psi_{k,L,a}(r) \Psi_{{k^\prime} ,L,a}(r) dr
\end{align*}

The above "equations", should be approximately OK for $k$ approximately equal to $  k^\prime$ as well. So, how $ \int _0^\infty \Psi_{k,L}(r) \Psi_{{k^\prime} ,L}( r) dr $ behaves, as a multiple of a delta function $\delta(k-k^\prime)$ is determined by the asymptotic forms of $\Psi_{k,L}$ and $\Psi_{k^\prime ,L}$.

For some number $N_L$ we will have

\begin{equation*}
\int ^\infty_0 \Psi_{k,L,a}(r) \Psi_{{k^\prime} ,L,a}(r) dr = N_L \delta(k-k^\prime)
\end{equation*}

There is no mention of the form of $\Psi_{k,L}$ or $\Psi_{k^\prime ,L}$ close to the scattering centre in the above.

Hence, the normalisation of a continuum/scattering wave function is insensitive to the functions form near to the scattering centre.