# How can you justify the delta function equation $\int_0^\infty~\delta(r)~dr = 1$?

Tags: dirac-delta

How can you have, when working with spherical polar coordinates ($r,\theta,\phi$), that
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^\infty~\delta(r)~dr = 1
\end{equation*}
When $\delta(x)$ is defined as

\begin{equation*}
\delta(x)=0~~~~~~if ~~x\neq0;~~~~~~\int_{- \infty}^{ \infty}~\delta (x)~dx=1
\end{equation*}
Hence,
\begin{equation*}
\delta(r)=0~~~~~~if ~~r\neq0;~~~~~~\int_{- \infty}^{ \infty}~\delta (r)~dr=1
\end{equation*}

Also please note that the above does not really make any sense, as a “radial coordinate” r, cannot take on negative values.

Comment: Yes and also $r=0$ is not a good point in the coordinate system either! I don't know why this got downvoted I think it's a good question.

Comment: I would say it depends on the integration limits. $\int_{[0,\infty)}\delta(r)dr=1$, but $\int_{(0,\infty)}\delta(r)dr=0$, as the entire "mass" in concentrated in $0$. The notation$\int_0^\infty$ is good enough for functions (where the value in a single point does not affect the integral), but not for proper distributions.

Answer (score -1):

You can’t justify the delta function equation $\int_0^\infty~\delta(r)~dr = 1$, working with the usual definition of the delta function.

You have to redefine what you mean by your symbol $\delta(x)$, hence $\delta(r)$.

To eventually work with a radial coordinate, r, you could take the following, as your basic definition of $\delta(x)$,

\begin{equation*}
\delta(x)=0~~~~~~if ~~x\neq0;~~~~~~\int_0^{ \infty}~\delta (x)~dx=1
\end{equation*}
Hence, for $\delta(r)$, we have the definition
\begin{equation*}
\delta(r)=0~~~~~~if ~~r\neq0;~~~~~~\int_0^{ \infty}~\delta (r)~dr=1~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)
\end{equation*}

where $r\in [0,\infty)$.

Barton, Reference 1, pg 33 , would call the above definition a ‘one-sided’ definition.

This definition contains the delta function equation that was to be justified.

**Reference:**

1. G.Barton, Elements of Greens Functions and Propagation. Potentials,
   Diffusion, and Waves, Clarendon Press Oxford, 1989.

NB: Pgs7-40 , contain material on the ‘Dirac Delta Function’

**Other Information**

You would then also have the rule,
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^{ \infty}~f(r)~\delta (r)~dr=f(0)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(2)
\end{equation*}

For those with access to Barton, (1) is almost the same as (1.4.12) on pg 33, and (2) is very similar to an equation on pg 9.

**RelatedQuestions**

[integral-of-delta-function-from-zero-to-infinity](http://https:/math.stackexchange.com/questions/3722748/integral-of-delta-function-from-zero-to-infinity?rq=1)

[dirac-function-integrated-from-infinity-to-0](http://https:/math.stackexchange.com/questions/3919730/dirac-function-integrated-from-infinity-to-0?noredirect=1&lq=1)